# The java.awt.Font.getStringBounds gives different results on openJdk11 and openJdk8

Tags: java, openjdk-11

I need to render PDF documents programmatically. I was using `itext7` library and openJdk8. All worked fine but I decided to change `openJdk8` on `openJdk11` and my documents rendered with shifting y coordinates position.
[image: This] result was gotten on `openJdk8` and [image: this] result was gotten on `openJdk11`.
This is my code:

```
public void renderText(Font font, String text, double x, double y, FontRendererContext ctx) {
    Rectangle2D rect = font.getStringBounds(text, ctx);   // In this place I get a different result.
    pdf.addText(text, x, (pageHeight - y - rect.getY()));
}
```

I'm providing test example to reproduce this issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args {
    final String text = "Simple text";
    // load font
    final InputStream arialIs = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fonts/arial.ttf");
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, arialIs);            
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
    Font newFont = font;
    newFont = newFont.deriveFont(14);
    
    // getting measuring
    final java.awt.geom.AffineTransform transform = newFont.getTransform();
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(transform, true, true);
    final Rectangle2D stringBounds = newFont.getStringBounds(text, frc);
    System.out.println(stringBounds);
}
```

How can I fix it on `openJdk11`?

Comment: It will be helpful to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And what is the different in value for `rect`?

Comment: @samabcde I always get this result ```java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-0.0,w=0.0,h=0.0]```

Comment: @samabcde I've added a reproducible example. If you have to reproduce, you should use ```openJdk11```

Comment: this is the result I run with openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25: `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-0.90527344,w=4.946289,h=1.1499023]`, is this what you expect?